# Getting error No outgoing sequence flow for the element with id 'Gateway_1bdqliv' could be selected for continuing the process

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to work on a simple Camunda embedded in springboot application scenario.
My model looks like this:

[Modeler bpmn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGgnC.png)

My Decision Model is this:

[Decision Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzlVh.png)

When I try to start the process on Camunda tasklist, I get the error - No outgoing sequence flow for the element with id 'Gateway_1bdqliv' could be selected for continuing the process.

[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui2Qv.png)

My sequence flows have the condition expression like this: #{PathToTake=="A"}; #{PathToTake=="B"}

I am new to Camunda, what am I doing wrong?

I want to give input as "A", and output to be 1 from the Decision table, so that the corresponding path is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your decisions model, I understand the process data PathToTake would have the values 1, 2 or 3. In your expressions on the sequence flows leaving the gateway you write you are checking for #{PathToTake=="A"}; #{PathToTake=="B"}. Shouldn't you be checking for the numerical values?